# How to style Squarespace product dropdown/select element with a top/bottom line & caret?

Tags: product, styling, squarespace

I'm looking for a way to style my product block to make it much more appealing... Right now, the block is as plain as it can be : http://www.dachshund-crane-s64k.squarespace.com/nouvelle-page (password is 'password'). The initial idea is one line at the top and one at the bottom + an arrow on the right, like here https://www.gfsmith.com/cranes-crest-pearl-white-watermarked. Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the more specific you can be about what you're trying to achieve, the better. Also, it's best to include what you've tried already in your question, including any code. Doing both of those will help avoid having the question closed by users for being too subjective or broad.

Answer (score 1):

The example site is using a custom dropdown implementation with JavaScript (and, in fact is not even using `select`/dropdown elements at all). Therefore, the dynamically changing appearance of the menu (growing/shrinking, caret rotation, etc.) can't be achieved with CSS alone, and would require a rather time-consuming rewrite of the Squarepspace's own UI to be done carefully so as not to break Squarespace's default ecommerce functions.

With that said, the top and bottom line along with the downward-pointing caret can be achieved with CSS in modern browsers (older browsers may not support this) by adding the following CSS via the CSS Editor:

```
.variant-option {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.variant-select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.variant-select-wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0.8em;
  height: 0.4em;
  background-color: #aaa;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 80% 0, 50% 50%, 20% 0, 0 0%, 50% 100%);
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 1em 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
.variant-option:first-child select {
  border-top: 1px solid #aaa !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help Brandon!
On Safari, the border-bottom line looks weird. Any idea how to make it straight?
I got two others questions so I'm sending you a mockup to make sure I'm clear: https://imgur.com/3J8Qloa.
Is it possible to separate the words and get the 'select' on the right next to the arrow? Finally, is it possible to create movement when you click on the arrow?
If I can contribute somehow as a thank you, please let me know as it's the least I can do.

Comment: The solution to the curved border ends was to add `border-radius: 0`, which I've added to the answer above. As to the other questions, yes it is possible to do with JavaScript (I've accomplished similar for clients) but it is a sizable project and can require maintenance over time as Squarespace changes the underlying markup (and so requires updating the custom JavaScript accordingly). It is more than can be offered as a simple solution here on SO. Also, don't forget to upvote/accept answers here on SO as applicable.

Comment: Thanks for the complementary solution Brandon, and for taking the time to explain everything. I wish I could accept the answer, sadly I don't have enough reputation it seems to "change the publicly displayed post score".